# Does anyone here have measurements of SRAM's direct-mount spline interface?

Tags: crankset, chainring, sram

The makerspace I work in purchased a new metal milling unit and I want to test its software's tolerances and mill a narrow-wide chainring.

I'm guessing it just consists of a circle with square splines and radial holes for the fixing bolts. I'm not seeing anything on my searches.

Comment: I poked around and didn't find the kind of detailed specs you need. SRAM has a very nice document on frame fit but not the details needed to replicate their product. Just a guess, but I don't think SRAM has published that kind of detail. You'd have to find someone who has done the measuring and published the details or get a sample part and measure it.

Comment: @DavidD I got one and measured it myself but I wanted to check if there's an actual document or patent image with measurements just to be sure. I guess this'll do then.